# Change height of android AppBarLayout on scroll

Tags: android, behavior, android-appbarlayout, android-nestedscrollview

I am trying to change height of android appBarLayout to make effect like this (example is from iOS but I am trying to do similar things in android):
When we scroll up appBar height of appBar should decrese and picture should scaled.
Example 1: http://take.ms/nxVJ7
Example 2: http://take.ms/jXQst

After some research and several attemptes I have some progress, but I have no idea what to do next.

This is my activity_profile:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="350dp"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
    android:minHeight="250dp"
    app:elevation="0dp"
    app:layout_behavior=".utils.behaviors.DisappearBehavior"
    >

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorWhite"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/status"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:text="online"/>

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/edit_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:background="@drawable/button_circle"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_edit"
                android:tint="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:visibility="gone"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/vip_status_icon"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/status"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_vip"
                android:tint="@color/colorPrimary"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/avatar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_avatar_placeholder"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Демин Сергей"
            android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_avatar_placeholder"
                />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_avatar_placeholder"
                />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_avatar_placeholder"
                />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorWhite"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavio">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:visibility="visible"/>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="visible">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</FrameLayout>
```

And DisappearBehavior:

```
public class DisappearBehavior extends CoordinatorLayout.Behavior<AppBarLayout> {

public DisappearBehavior(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

@Override
public boolean onStartNestedScroll(
        CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, AppBarLayout child, View directTargetChild, View target, int nestedScrollAxes) {
    if (nestedScrollAxes == ViewCompat.SCROLL_AXIS_VERTICAL) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

@Override
public void onNestedPreScroll(
        CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, AppBarLayout child, View target, int dx, int dy, int[] consumed) {
    consumed = new int[2];
    consumed[1] = dy;
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = child.getLayoutParams();
    Log.d("Behavior", "dy = " + dy);
    params.height -= dy;
    child.setLayoutParams(params);
}

@Override
public void onNestedScroll(
        CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, AppBarLayout child, View target, int dxConsumed, int dyConsumed,
        int dxUnconsumed,
        int dyUnconsumed) {
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = child.getLayoutParams();
    child.setLayoutParams(params);
    int xxx = child.getBottom();
    Log.d("Behavior", "height = " + params.height + " " + xxx);
}

@Override
public void onStopNestedScroll(CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, AppBarLayout child, View target) {
    super.onStopNestedScroll(coordinatorLayout, child, target);
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = child.getLayoutParams();
    child.setLayoutParams(params);
    int xxx = child.getBottom();
    Log.d("Behavior", "stop height = " + params.height + " " + xxx);
}
}
```

In the result I have effect when both appBarLayout and FrameLayout with content scrolling simultaneously (I'll try to add images if I'll found a way how to do it. I need more than 10 reputation. image3, image4).
Also there is some starnge effect. When you scroll up (for example) slowly you could see text on screen moving up and the again down. Smth like quake effect.

As you see I have logs in the code and they says me that dy is positive and negative when I scroll in one direction.
Log for slow up scroll for example:

```
dy = 42
height = 924 1026
dy = -36
height = 960 984
dy = 43
height = 917 1020
dy = -37
height = 954 977
dy = 42
height = 912 1014
dy = -36
height = 948 972
dy = 48
height = 808 916
dy = -44
height = 852 868
dy = 46
height = 806 912
dy = -46
height = 852 866
stop height = 852 866
```

I understand that all problems come `AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior` but I do not understand what to change.

Comment: Images for my current situation. Yes! I can add it here. image 3: http://take.ms/Xr9bf and image 4: http://take.ms/ldBaLX.

Comment: Did you find solution?

Comment: Sorry, but no. I have little amount of free time now, maybe sometimes later I will find answer how to do this.